# How do I delete all pictures off an iPod Touch?

Tags: ipod-touch, graphics

I'm running Windows iTunes and have copied my DCIM folder to back it up, now I want to delete all the pictures like I would on a digital camera, but the folder appears to be write protected and unchangeable.

What's the easiest way clear out all the pictures in lieu of doing it one-by-one.  I'm sure it's obvious, but it appears to be non-obvious.

Answer (score 2):

View the list of photos in the Camera Roll (or other album), hit the Actions button in the upper-right (the button with the rightward-pointing arrow). Now, when you tap on a picture or video, it greys out a little and gets a checkmark. Check all the items you want to delete and hit the red delete button at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Kinda sucks that that'll take 10 minutes to do and tapping the wrong thing before delete will totally wipe out all that tapping.

Comment: i have now like 4223 photos on my ipod touch 5 64g... 24Gigabyte guys and my ipod is full, so I'm trying different methodes but it always crashes.. that tapping gonna make for me 2weeks for deleting those pictures and videos..